# How to calculate seconds between two timestamps in Impala?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I do not see an Impala function to subtract two `datestamps` and return seconds (or minutes) between the two.
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html

Comment: You might use the method `unix_timestamp(timestamp datetime)` to convert the 2 `timestamp` values into `bigint`, then do the subtraction ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

unix_timestamp(finish_time)-unix_timestamp(start_time) will give you the seconds between them.